# how to prevent Parent Divistions Properties to child Division in CSS

Tags: html, css

```
<body>
<div id=one>
    <div id=two>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

in css if we give some properties to div #one , those also coming to #two. How to prevent this .

Comment: It's normal CSS behavior, it's _cascading_ stylesheet. Children can inherit some properties from their parent.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't begin an id with a number, you need to put quotes around the ids.
You really shouldn't ask this question until you have learnt the basics of html.

```
<div id="something1"></div>
```

Comment: thanQ for telling .. by the way i did't got my answer. and we can give id value without using quotes.

Comment: @Sriram You need to learn the basics and follow best practices of HTML. Also you didn't supply the CSS you are using. Learn the basics of HTML I believe you are wasting your own time.